# Intel audio card not recognized in KDE Neon (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)

Tags: drivers, sound, alsa

Good morning everyone,

I have a new laptop, an Asus ZenBook 3, onwhich I have just install KDE Neon, which is based on Ubuntu 16.04LTS. Everything works perfectly well, except that I have no sound, and no sound option in the bottom menu bar !
I have done some research, and I have found that my audio card does not show in the system audio settings, and that the folder /proc/asound does not seem to exist. I have already tried to reinstall alsa several times, with little success.
However, the card is listed when I use lspci :

```
etienne@etienne-ZenBook:~$ sudo lspci | grep [Aa]udio
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9d71 (rev 21)
```

and it also works fine in the dual-boot Windows 10.

What can I do for it to be recognized by my system ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: I have this exact problem (Zenbook 3, dual boot Windows) but with Ubuntu Budgie. Have you found a solution? I see the sound control and get very distorted sound though.